# How can I copy an older version of my project into a new folder?

Tags: git

I have a project I have been working on for a while, and it's not 100% complete, and there are some missing features that I did not finish writing them completely. And during that, I have decided to make a big refactor to my project.

Now the code no longer works because I did not complete the refactoring yet, I still need some time.

The boss wants me to implement one feature as fast as possible.

So I want to keep my progress in the refactoring, but I want somehow to roll back to my previous commit.

But I don't want to lose my progress in the new refactor, so I think the best solution would be to copy the older commit into a newer folder, and there I can complete the feature they're stuck on.

And during that I can finish my refactor peacefully.

How can I keep my current progress, but roll back just for a bit of time to complete a feature, publish that, so they can use it online, then roll forward again into where I stopped while refactoring.

This kind of idea isn't fitting in my head, and I'm not able to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Very roughly, the three ways to basically "put things aside for a moment" are 1) stashing then switching branch 2) temporary commiting then switching branch 3) using an additional worktree.

Answer (score 1):

If the differences between the current differences and the last commit are solely due to your working on your refactoring, you can create a new branch:

```
git checkout -b refactor
```

and commit your changes there. Then, you can always go back to the branch you started working on

```
git checkout develop
```

(`develop` is a clean branch not including any local experiments) and start working on the feature your boss asked for

```
git checkout -b feature
```

and implement the changes there. Whenever you feel like coming back to your refactoring coding, simply change between branches with

```
git checkout refactor
```

and

```
git checkout feature
```